# Why would a error free code not give the expected result on one machine but yes on the other

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm having a problem with a part of code. It should work,since it is error free, and it has no logical problems since it does work on someone else pc, but on my  computer the result is the same as the input.
code(runnable):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class RAngle{
public:
   int x,y,l;
   RAngle(){}
   RAngle(int i,int j,int k){
      x=i,y=j,l=k;
   }
   bool operator<(const RAngle& rhs)const{
      if(l < rhs.l){
         return true;
        }
      return 0;
  }
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const RAngle& ra){
    out << ra.x << " " << ra.y << " " << ra.l;
    return out;
  }
  friend istream& operator >>( istream& is, RAngle &ra){
    is >> ra.x;
    is >> ra.y;
    is >> ra.l;
    return is ;
  }
};
void descrSort(vector <RAngle> &l){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<l.size();i++){
        cout<<l[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout << "==================" << endl;
    sort(l.begin(),l.end());
    reverse(l.begin(),l.end());
    for(unsigned i=0; i<l.size();i++){
        cout<<l[i]<<endl;
    }
}
void readData(vector <RAngle> &l){
   RAngle r;
   ifstream f_in;
   f_in.open("test.txt",ios::in);
   for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
      f_in >> r;
      l.push_back(r);
   }
}
int main(){
   vector <RAngle> a;
   readData(a);
   descrSort(a);

   return 0;
  }
```

DATA:

```
1 7 31
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 5 1
10 5 1
1 1 9
10 3 10
4 5 7
5 4 15
2 3 25
1 7 31
```

The output on other machine(only print part after, the descr sort):

```
1 7 31
2 3 25
5 4 15
10 3 10
1 1 9
4 5 7
3 3 3
2 2 2
10 5 1
4 5 1
```

on my computer(hoel output):

```
1 7 31

2 2 2

3 3 3

4 5 1

10 5 1

1 1 9

10 3 10

4 5 7

5 4 15

2 3 25

==================
1 7 31

2 2 2

3 3 3

4 5 1

10 5 1

1 1 9

10 3 10

4 5 7

5 4 15

2 3 25
```

Comment: Actually when it works on one machine and doesn't on another that's almost a textbook implication that your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a problem, but it's certainly unusual to define friend free functions in a class' body.

Comment: I doubt you posted the actual output - note that the code prints the data twice, once unsorted, once sorted, with "=====" in between.

Comment: @MarkB if you knwo were that problem is please let me know i'm satring and trying for like 2h to fix this and have no clue were to start... tried everything i could think at...

Comment: Precisely, what compilation and execution environments are we talking about?

Comment: @MarkB: I doubt this will be undefined behavior, at least I couldn't find any (and not all inconsistencies between two runs of a program can be accounted to UB).

Comment: @jpalecek well i got it from that someone else that tried my code... all i did diferent is about printing... that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: "it has no logical problems since it does work on someone else pc". So this is the opposite of http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html

Comment: @user1388172: Post the **real output from the program**.

Comment: looks like `sort` and `reverse` combine to do exactly nothing on your computer ...

Comment: @user1388172: If you did the printing different, it's not surprising that it prints something else.

Comment: You're missing copy constructor.

Comment: @jrok: should not be a problem, since simple (compiler-generated) copy c-tor should work for his class.

Comment: @Walter: or maybe, he's showing us only output from the first output loop, that is *before* `sort` and `reverse`.

Comment: @jpalecek I bet that is it ;-(

Comment: @jpalecek & @Walter i`m not showing you anything  wrong i have been looking voer this code a few times and it is the same thing were i use print as  long as i print the specified data at a given moment....

Comment: @user1388172: no offence, but you're not to be trusted what differences are important and what aren't. The reason is simply that you wrote some code that doesn't work as you expect, that you need help with. Therefore, you don't understand it properly. Therefore, you don't get to decide what differences matter and what don't. Post the code you actually ran, and the output you actually saw. If you can't post your real code for some reason, write a simpler test case that demonstrates the same problem, and actually run that.

Comment: @SteveJessop , well let's say i understand, i updated the `cout` I used, and the code were it prints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your code has an error.  C and C++ let things compile and run that actually have errors in them.  Like this:

```
int i;
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Will do different things on different machines.  I would call it an error.  The compiler won't.

Now as for where your *error* is, here is my "use a debugger" speech.  Use a debugger.  It will take you less time to use a debugger and have a decent chance of finding the error than it did for me to read your code to see if anything jumped out.  Compile with `-g`.  Google "gdb cheat sheet."  Run with gdb.  Follow the cheat sheet.  See where your code does something unexpected.

Seems smart to do this on the machine that is giving the wrong output.  And see where it's doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, i`ll give it a try write away

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @djechlin said, what you most likely have is "undefined behavior".

Most programming languages strictly define what can and can't be done, and compiler writers use that to generate compiler errors. Undefined behavior, on the other hand, means that it is up to the compiler writer and system; anything can happen - it can work correctly, it can erase your boot sector, zombie Alan Turing rise and feast on your brains, etc.

For example, using an uninitialized variable like so:

```
int i; 
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

on some compilers will give you a pattern like 0xCECECECE in debug builds to help find uninitialized variables. In release builds it might be set to 0 by the compiler, or it might be garbage data.

Comment: as far as i know c++ offers the safety, that an init int will be 0;(offtopic)

Comment: @user1388172: No, that only holds for global/static variables. Uninitialized automatic variables have undefined contents (although IDK if that's UB)

Comment: And that's the worst thing about UB - if an SO user with 22k rep doesn't know if something fairly mundane like uninitialized variables are UB, how can anyone hope to know every bit of UB? I would venture a guess that every single programmer does things that create UB and it just happens to work every single time - I'm sure that I do.

Comment: It is not as simple as it might seem. In C++ it **is** UB to try to read the value of an uninitialized variable. In C99 it is that as well, but in C11 the result is just *unspecified* on hardware that doesn't trap on invalid values. I guess most 22k users just always write `int i = 0;` without bothering to figure out if it might work uninitialized.

Comment: I didn't say simple, I said mundane - there's a difference ;)  And I didn't mean anything by it besides to point out how esoteric all the rules can be, which I think you underscored with that explanation. (And I didn't know any of the changes either, I just always assumed it was UB :)

Comment: I was even arguing with someone the other day, who said a C++ object that has been default initialized is *not* "uninitialized", even if it's a type for which default initialization "performs no initialization". Hence the text saying that reading an uninitialized object is UB, is irrelevant to `int i;`. Hence C++03 is the same as C11 in this respect. Which I can't directly refute, because the standard doesn't define "uninitialized". So I'm a 100k user (very nearly), most of that earned in the C++ tag, who was combing the standard for that exact issue a few days ago, and I don't know either :-)

Comment: @carpat - as a professional C++ developer I am trained to avoid bad practice, of which UB is a subset, and not know the technicalities of when something is UB or not.  Defining an int without init-ing it to 0 (or its real life value) is BP, so I don't need to know when it's UB and when it's not.